# java: Is it possible to know which constructor an enumeration item uses to be initialized?

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, enums, initialization

Just as the title say, I was wondering if it is programmatically possible to get to know the constructor that an enumeration item uses to be initialized, I think that if there is such mechanism it should be accessible by using reflection but I have not been able to find anything like that, to be more specific:

**What I have**

```
enum AnEnum {

    E1(1),
    E1(1, 2);

    int v;

    AnEnum(int p1) {
        v = p1;
    }

    AnEnum(int p1, int p2) {
        v = p1 + p2;
    }

}
```

**What I need** is a mechanism to tell me whether the instance was initialized by using the one or the two argument constructor, and even better would be if I can get the parameters used to initialize it.

Comment: _"What I need is a mechanism to tell me"_ How do you want to be told? Why not just use a print statement in both your constructors with all the information?

Comment: The issue is that I am coding an utility that allows me "introspect" in the code, something like decompiling it, therefore I wont be able to have access or modify the source at will in all the cases. So the better I can recreate the code the better.

Comment: There is no "history" for objects to tell you how they have been composed - unless you add it to the class' code. - This is a weird requirement. What would you derive from this info? The object is the way it is when you inspect it, no matter its past.

Comment: @laune As I said in my previous comment, if I am recreating the code the best thing to do would be to determine how exactly it was written. nevertheless I know that in my example It would not matter since I can recreate the code as: `E1(1),E2(3)`

Answer (score 2):

Bytecode tools like [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) allow you to see how a certain enum value is constructed.

Try java -classpath "asm.jar;asm-util.jar;yourjar.jar" AnEnum and look into the clinit method:

```
...
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "temp/AnEnum", "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;II)V", false);
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTSTATIC, "temp/AnEnum", "E1", "Ltemp/AnEnum;");
...
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "temp/AnEnum", "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;III)V", false);
mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTSTATIC, "temp/AnEnum", "E2", "Ltemp/AnEnum;");
```

you can see that E1 is called with signature (String, int, int) and E2 is called with signature (String, int, int, int). The leading (String, int) is probably the string name and the numeric value of the Enum value, so you should only be interested in the remaining arguments.

Comment: thats what I was talking about, by any chance is there an example ?

Comment: your problem is very special. Besides - extracting the required information from the class initializer affords that you are familiar with java byte code, data flow analysis and the tool asm.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to detect which constructor was called, but the constructor could simply store the parameter values which you can access.  In this example I use the Object type of Integer. If the second constructor was used and there was no p2, it's value will be null.

```
enum AnEnum {

    E1(1),
    E2(1, 2);

    int v;
    Integer p1;
    Integer p2;

    AnEnum(int p1) {
        this.v = p1;
        this.p1 = p1;
    }

    AnEnum(int p1, int p2) {
        this.v = p1 + p2;
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    public Integer getP1() {
        return this.p1;
    }

    public Integer getP2() {
        return this.p2;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the official solution following a clean ood, but the question is different i think.

Comment: Ah yes, i see. My solution applies to classes in general. Now while you can reflect the fields of the enum to get the instances, you still won't be able to determine which constructor was used without disassembling the static initialiser of the class.

Comment: yes i agree with that (that's why i wrote it :). I meant you would need to disassemble the code if the enum's code could not be modified.